# ZF2 route name not found when creating module, controller or action

Tags: zend-framework2, url-routing, acl

My application has the following Module structure
module
 + Application
 + UserAdmin

Anything I want it common for all the modules I am defining it under "Application". With this I have implemented ACL in Application/Module.php. If the ACL is not allowed, I redirect the flow to a route "useradmin" defined in UserAdmin/config/module.config.php.

During runtime I do not have any problem and I am able to route all the actions to this route. However, I am trying to create a new module or controller or action using zf.php under vendor/bin directory of the application.

I issue the following command

```
vendor/bin/zf.php create controller UserGroup UserAdmin
```

and I get the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Route with name "useradmin" not found' in /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/SimpleRouteStack.php:328
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/zf2/dwam/module/Application/Module.php(54): Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack->assemble(Array, Array)
#1 [internal function]: Application\Module->Application\{closure}(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#2 /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#3 /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('route', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#4 /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(296): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('route', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#5 /var/www/zf2/dwam/ven in /var/www/zf2/dwam/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/SimpleRouteStack.php on line 328
```

The line in Application/Module.php which throws this error is

```
 $url      = $router->assemble( array( ), array( "name" => "useradmin" ) );
```

When I comment this line and any reference to $url, the new controller is created. I have tried finding different ways to create the url from Module.php and I am not able to find any.

I have changed the name to a route name I have defined in "Application/config/module.config.php" and it still does not work

useradmin route

```
    'useradmin' => array(
        'type' => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route' => '/useradmin',
            'defaults' => array (
                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'UserAdmin\Controller',
                'controller' => 'Index',
                'action' => 'index',
            ),
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Please include the `useradmin` route in your question.

Comment: @Kunal I do not think there is a problem with the useradmin route, because during runtime there are no errors. only when I use the zf.php tool to add module/controller/action I have an issue. In any case the route has been added in the question